# Apache VHost Intranet Setup

Tags: apache, vhosts

Hi I would like to ask some help on setting up my webserver to access over my network.

Basically I have more projects on the **www** folder. For example I have 2 website that I want to access on different machine.

Heres my vhost config.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName website1
    ServerAlias website1
    DocumentRoot "/www/website1"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost my_ip_add:8080>
    ServerName website2
    ServerAlias website2
    DocumentRoot "/www/website2"
</VirtualHost>
```

And I also configure the **/etc/hosts** file.

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.0.1    website1
my_ip_add    website2
```

What I want to is to access **website2** from other machine.

What happen is when I put **http://my_ip_add:8080/** on my browser it was *"ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"*, but when I use **http://my_ip_add/** it render **website1**.

How can I access the website2 on other machine? Is there is missing on my configuration?

I hope someone can help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` probably is the result of the fact that you do not open port 8080 in your configuration, but only port 80. The second effect when requesting `http://my_ip_add` is to be expected, since that single virtual host listening on port 80 automatically acts as fallback host...

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice this. I added `Listen 8080` on my vhost configa and it's working now. Thanks.

Comment: It was not _that_ comment above I referred to below. What you have now is a possible setup, but unnecessary complex. The setup described in my answer below is the preferred one, since it is much more simple whilst allowing more flexibility at the same time. Anyway, glad you got your stuff working! Have fun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why so complex? Why don't you deliver both sites on the same port? That is what virtual hosts are for. You only have to take care to always request the two sites by their host name as resolved in your local name resolution...

Simplify your virtual hosts definition:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName website1
    DocumentRoot "/www/website1"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName website2
    DocumentRoot "/www/website2"
</VirtualHost>
```

Your local name resolution should resolve *both* host names:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
my_ip_add    website1
my_ip_add    website2
```

now you can make these requests from all systems with above name resolution:

- http://website1
- http://website2

Comment: Thanks. That was my previous config, and I can only access with that locally on  the server. But I want to access the website2 on other computer/device.

I also try host both website on different port so I can access them via http://my_ip_add:80/ (website1) and http://my_ip_add:8080/ (website2). But I can't still work it correctly.

Comment: The above certainly works. You must have missed something in your setup. Most likely one of these two things: 1. the name resolution must work as described on the system you make the request from and 2. you have to open port 80 in the firewall of the serving system to allow requests from the requesting system. If you are really sure both points are fullfilled, then please explain what you actually mean by "I can only access with that locally". In other words: "what is the error you get?"

Comment: Yes it works locally (I mean the host server), I can access both sites [http://website1/](http://website1/) and [http://website2/](http://website2). But not on other device.

Comment: Sigh. Did you even bother to read my last comment? Your last comment does not read like that...